# Intuitive MOBA orbiting camera (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I hardcoded a moba style camera. The camera moves throughout the XZ plane when the cursor is close to the edges of the screen. 
[View front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lsV0.png)

Problems arose when I implemented a orbiting camera functionality. Once the camera orbits towards the opposite side of the character, moving the camera with the cursor is no longer very intuitive.

[Opposite view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrNQx.png)

This is due to the fact that the hovering movement of the camera is harcoded to increase Z-value when the cursor is close to upper edge, decrease Z-value when the cursor is close to bottom edge, increase X-value when the cursor is close to right edge, and decrease X-value when the cursor is close to left edge.

How could I script the hovering (XZ plane) of the camera so that it always moves with respect to itself(upper edge = forward, lower edge = back, left edge = left, right edge = right) regardles of the angle of vision? Thanks for considering my question.

Answer (score 0):

Without code examples, its difficult yo know where you need to put it, but you should utilise Mathf.sin and Mathf.cos with respect to the angle of your camera to work out how much to shift each axis.

Keep in mind you will need to work on both axis when calculating the shifts, eg your translation on x axis would need to use the cos of x input and sin of z input or vice versa depending on your actual implementation.